# Reportlab build table of tables doesn't repeat rows

Tags: python, reportlab

I am new to reportlab, and I've been pleased so far, but I've come to a situation I don't know how to fix.  I am trying to build a table with subtables, as I have rows that have different column counts, so essentially I'm trying to build a table where each row is a table by itself.  That seems to work, in that the Table constructor completes successfully and returns a valid table.  What's strange, though, is that when I try to build the document (a SimpleDocTemplate instance), I get a "Table instance has no attribute '**len**'" error.  My report generation code is:

```
        #create the document and data list
    doc = TimeEntryReportDocTemplate(response)
    elements = []

    #add the Sustainable Development and Construction header
    elements.append(add_sdc())

    #add the header rows
    elements.append(add_header(start_date, end_date, department, unit, employee, project_name))

    #create the column header table
    t = create_column_header_table(grouping_type)
    results = []
    results.append(t)
    #elements.append(t)

    #get the grouped line item tables for inclusion
    #elements = tabulate_line_items(line_items, grouping_type, elements)
    results = tabulate_line_items(line_items, grouping_type, results)

    final_table = Table(results, repeatRows=1)
    elements.append(final_table)

    doc.build(elements)
```

print final_table actually shows the data wrapped in a Table(...data...) # end table.  Why when I try to build it does it not work?  I've tested each of my methods that returns a table, and they work.  If I just build the document with the "elements" variable, the document builds fine.  I just need to repeat the first row in the elements collection on each page, which is why I'm trying to build a table of tables.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: Well, I see at least one possible issue. I think you should be calling `doc.build([final_table])`, and the error you are getting is probably because `final_table` is not a list.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and still got the "Table instance has no attribute 'len'" error.  I created a new empty list and then appended final_table to that list, and built the doc with the new list and received "'list' object has no attribute 'getKeepWithNext'"

Comment: Now getting iteration over non-sequence, after some changes to the code.  Updating code to show current (lot of changes in the background)

Comment: Have you considered taking a different approach: rather than nesting tables you could accomplish the same sort of thing using a header and a multi-column style frame layout.

Comment: i've created tables and every page my tables have a header. I'm not getting what you want here. If possible, provide a simple working code, so that I can from there. I personally don't think this is a problem, maybe you faced an error when the table is too long.